# build sums of columns of pandas dataframe despite missing some data

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and wanted to build sums ov every column.

My dataframe looks like:

```
                        Buy_He  Sell_He  Buy_Tr  Sell_Tr  Buy_Am  Sell_Am  
2009-08-01 00:00:00       28        0       0        0       0       20   
2009-08-01 00:15:00       28        0       0        0       0       20   
2009-08-01 00:30:00       28        0       0        0       0       20   
2009-08-01 00:45:00       28        0       0        0       0       20   
2009-08-01 01:00:00       NaN    NaN       15        0       0       19   
2009-08-01 01:15:00       NaN    NaN       15        0       0       19   
2009-08-01 01:30:00       NaN    NaN       15        0       0       19   
2009-08-01 01:45:00       NaN    NaN       15        0       0       19   
2009-08-01 02:00:00       NaN    NaN        0        0       0       57
```

and so on. I WANTED TO HAVE THE SUM OF EVERY COLUMNS IN THE LAST ROW.

I have tried `sum_col = sum('Buy_He',NaN.rm=TRUE)`

But first, it does not worket. Second, it would create only a sum of one column.

Is there any possibility two get THE SUM OF EVERY COLUMNS IN THE LAST ROW, while ignore the sporadic NaN?

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it to get the sum of one column with your command.
With a one-liner:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_records([df.sum().to_dict()])])
```

You are concatenating the existing dataframe with a 1-row DataFrame made from the sum of each row.
Tested it with this small dataframe as input
     df = pd.DataFrame([{"a":np.nan, "b":15},{"a":2,"b":16}])
and there was no problem with NaN's